# APIATO url search criteria - is null and is not null values

Tags: php, laravel, apiato

Is there any way that we can search null value in apiato, for example `api.domain.test/v1/endpoint?search=email:null` I want to query null values to display as 1 group, any suggestions or advise on how to do so. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot search null value in a URL like that but my idea is you can compare the string in the URL if the value == null you can check the condition and query the data that you want
Ex: api.domain.test/v1/endpoint?search=email:null

```
if ($request->email == 'email:null')
{
     return 'query that you want';
}
```